# Values not setting on slice with .xs() and .get_level_values()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndex dataframe that looks like this:

```
                    count

   year   item
   1922   foo       0
          bar       0
   1923   foo       0
          bar       0
   1924   foo       0
          bar       0
```

I'm trying to set values for multiple years and certain items by slicing the dataframe with `.get_level_values()` and `.xs()`. For example:

```
lst = [1923, 1924]

df[df.index.get_level_values('year').isin(lst)].xs('foo', level=1).loc[:, 'count'] = 3
```

This doesn't throw any errors, but the value remains 0:

```
In: df[df.index.get_level_values('year').isin(lst)].xs('foo', level=1)
Out: 

       count
year
1923   0
1924   0
```

How can I change values in these slices of my dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need only filtering:

```
lst = [1923, 1924]

m1 = df.index.get_level_values('year').isin(lst)
m2 = df.index.get_level_values('item') == 'foo'

df.loc[m1 & m2, 'count'] = 3
print (df)
           count
year item       
1922 foo       0
     bar       0
1923 foo       3
     bar       0
1924 foo       3
     bar       0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do:

```
df.loc[(1923, 'foo'), 'count'] = 3
```

Comment: You know what, I oversimplified my sample question, I actually need to select from multiple years so `.loc` doesn't work this way, sorry, and upvoted for the confusion